# Ayuda sobre un ejercicio de ArrayList

Tags: java, archivo, arraylist

Estoy intentando hacer un ejercicio en el que tengo que usar la clase *ArrayList* y no encuentro la manera de hacerlo. El enunciado del ejercicio es el siguiente:

> En una terminal de teletipo existe un carácter de retroceso que permite cancelar el último carácter.
>
> **Por ejemplo:** si el carácter de retroceso es `/`, entonces la línea
>   `abc/d//e` será interpretada como `ae`.
>
> Existe también un carácter anulador que elimina todos los caracteres ingresados hasta el momento, suponga que ese carácter es `&`.
>
> Realice un método que dada una tira de caracteres terminadas con `*` (leída del archivo “*Fuente.txt*”) ejecute las operaciones indicadas si se encuentra con el carácter `/` o el `&`. Debe por último imprimir la tira resultante.

Les paso la clase *Teletipo.java*:

```
package terminal_teletipo;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class Teletipo {
    int cont = 0;
    private String secuencia;

    File f = new File("D:\\Proyectos Java\\List_Interface\\Fuente.txt");
    ArrayList<Character> lista = new ArrayList<Character>();

    public void File_Test() {
        System.out.println("El archivo existe? : " + f.exists() + " ");
        if (f.exists() == true) System.out.println("Direccion: " + f.getAbsolutePath());
        else System.out.println("El archivo no existe");
    }

    public void setArrayList() throws FileNotFoundException, IOException {
        FileReader r = new FileReader(f);
        BufferedReader b = new BufferedReader(r);
        secuencia = b.readLine();
        System.out.println(secuencia);
        for (int i = 0; i < secuencia.length(); i++) {
            lista.add(secuencia.charAt(i));
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Pon el código que llevas hasta el momento

Comment: ya agregue el codigo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

no se si es estrictamente necesario que uses un ArrayList pero yo te recomendaría usar únicamente un String y recorrelo haciendo uso de sus métodos. En todo caso te dejo un método que a mí me ha funcionado perfectamente según la descripción de tu problema:

```
public void applyRules(){
    String output = ""; //esta es la salida
    int l = lista.size();
    for (int i = 0;  i < l; i++){ // recorres el arraylist
        char c = lista.get(i);    //obtienes el caracter de cada posición
        if(c >= 'a' && c <= 'z'){ //si es una letra la agregas a la salida
            output += c;                
        }else if(c == '/'){       //aqui borras el último caracter siempre que exista uno
            if(output.length() > 0)
                output = output.substring(0, output.length()-1);
        }else if(c == '&'){       //aquí borras toda la salida
            output = "";
        }else if(c == '*'){       //y si el caracter es el final detienes el ciclo
            break;
        }
    }
    System.out.println(output);
}
```

Solo hace falta aplicar algunos métodos de la clase String y ArrayList. Te recomiendo leas la [API de Java](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/) para que puedas aprender por ti mismo.

Answer (score 0):

Es un ejercicio, por lo que la idea es que la solución la crees tú.
Para guiarte y viendo el problema, debieras ordenar el problema y sacar en limpio los pasos a seguir (el 4° es solo un concejo):

1. guardar todos los caracteres
2. iterar por todos los caracteres y ejecutar lo que indica cada uno
3. guardar en otra lista el resultado
4. crear una función que lea esta ultima lista y la imprima a consola tomando el carácter * como salto de linea

el primero lo tienes listo, por lo que te falta el resto
¿cómo itero y ejecuto los 'comandos' según el carácter?
podría ser con switch
Ex:

```
List<String> clean = new ArrayList();
int hlpr =0;
boolean ampersand = false;
String ayudante = "";
for(int i=0; i<lista.size();i++){
    String caracter = lista.get(i)+"";
    switch(caracter){
    case "/":
        ayudante = this.retroceder(ayudante); /*una función para limpiar el ultimo carácter en caso de haber*/
        break;
    case "&":
        ampersand = true; /*se indica que no siga guardando hasta el salto de linea*/
        ayudante = ""; /*borra lo que se llevaba, no?*/
        break;
    case "*":
        ampersand = false;/*se indica que ahora se puede volver a guardar caracteres*/
        clean.add(ayudante); /*se guarda resultado*/
        ayudante = ""; /*se limpia para comenzar de nuevo*/
        break;
    default:
        if(!ampersand)
            ayudante+=caracter;
        break;
    }
}
```

igualmente podrían ser varios if else.
de todas formas esto igualmente se podría ir haciendo a medida que se lee el archivo y evitando los pasos 1 y 2 e iterar 2 veces por lo mismo, pero es solo un comentario.